# How to send email via table data as email laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to send an email via Laravel that has table data attached to it and I'm having some trouble. Here is a snippet of the code I'm running:

```
public function pdfview(Request $request)
{
    $items = DB::table("motor_vehicles")->get();
    view()->share('vehicles', $items);


    if ($request->has('download')) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');

        $this->sendEmail();

        return $pdf->download('pdfview.pdf');
    }

    return view('pdfview');
}


public function sendEmail()
{
    Mail::send(['text' => 'mail'], $info, function ($message) {

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');

        $message->to('inchiriseri@gmail.com', 'Itai Chiriseri')->subject('Sent Table Data');

        $message->from('inchiriseri@gmail.com', 'Itai Chiriseri');

        $message->attachData($pdf->output(), 'pdfview.pdf');

    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "trouble" i.e. are you getting any errors?

Comment: what sort of trouble are you having? you haven't mentioned what seems to be an issue